# Alternative to Modulus in Lua

Tags: lua, modulus

In Lua, as you may know, arrays start with index 1.

In other languages I will often use modulus to make a value oscillate through the members of an array, for example:

```
i = (i + 1) % array.length
return array[1]
```

How can I do this in Lua, where `array[0]` is nil by default.

Comment: `i = i % #array + 1; return array[i]`

Answer (score 3):

Like [Egor said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103713/alternative-to-modulus-in-lua#comment91158615_52103713),

First do the modulo and then increment the value.

If `i` is equal to the length it will end up 0. Incrementing that will result in `1`. Every other value just gets incremented.

This only works when incrementing by 1 though. For bigger steps you can do

```
i = (i+n-1)% #array + 1
```